# mysql random rows

Tags: mysql, random, subquery

how to form a query to select **'m' rows** randomly from a query result which has **'n' rows**.

**for ex;** 5 rows from a query result which has 50 rows

i try like as follows but it errors

```
 select * from (select * from emp where alphabet='A' order by sal desc) order by rand() limit 5;
```

u can wonder that why he needs sub query, i need 5 different names from a set of top 50 resulted by inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

or from your query result:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM t WHERE x=y ) tt
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Comment: 2nd query result error as follows :
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: just add 'some_name' (without the quotes) after the closing parenthese

Comment: note that `order by rand()` becomes expensive when the number of rows becomes large

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the number to use as 'm' (limit)

```
TRUNCATE((RAND()*50),0);
```

...substitute 50 with n.
To check it try the following:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE((RAND()*50),0);
```

I should warn that this could return 0 as a result, is this ok for you?

For example you could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

...and store the result in a variable named *totalRows* for example. Then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT TRUNCATE((RAND()*?),0);
```

where you substitute the '?' with the *totalRows* variable, according to the tech stack you are using.
Is it clearer now? If not please add more information to your question.

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand your solution .can u tell me more please